# How to detect if a file is a favicon in PHP?

Tags: php, file-upload, favicon, ico

I need to check if an uploaded file is a favicon type and I need do it in a secure way.

If I upload a favicon file through an input file and print the `$_FILES` variable, I can see that the variable has the following type value:

`image/vnd.microsoft.icon`

I know that I can check if that value matches that, but I think that the user can dumper it. If someone could give me some tip I'd be grateful

Comment: Use `Fileinfo` to get the mime type and then compare that to your desired mime type. http://php.net/Fileinfo

Comment: Thanks for your comment. And is it a secure way to do check it? I want to be sure that user doesn't tamper it. If so, you can leave me your comment as answer and I will mark it as right answer @CharlotteDunois

Comment: `The functions in this module try to guess the content type and encoding of a file by looking for certain magic byte sequences at specific positions within the file. While this is not a bullet proof approach the heuristics used do a very good job.` It's much better than relying on `$_FILES[...]['mime']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want avoid using any external tools, https://github.com/lordelph/icofileloader provides a native PHP method for parsing .ico files

```
$loader = new Elphin\IcoFileLoader\IcoFileService;
try {
    /** @var Elphin\IcoFileLoader\Icon $icon */
    $icon = $loader->fromFile('/path/to/icon.ico');

    //perform further inspection or render the icon as an image here...

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    //not an .ico file
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use various tools:

**FileInfo**

You can use [FileInfo](http://php.net/manual/book.fileinfo.php) directly from PHP:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
echo finfo_file($finfo, 'the_file_to_check.ico');
// Should print something like 'image/x-icon'
finfo_close($finfo);
```

If FileInfo is setup on your system, this is probably the easiest way to go.

**ImageMagick**

ImageMagick goes a step further by actually decoding the content of the file, listing the embedded images:

```
$ identify favicon.ico
favicon.ico[0] ICO 16x16 16x16+0+0 32-bit sRGB 15.1KB 0.000u 0:00.000
favicon.ico[1] ICO 32x32 32x32+0+0 32-bit sRGB 15.1KB 0.000u 0:00.000
favicon.ico[2] ICO 48x48 48x48+0+0 32-bit sRGB 15.1KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

(called from the command line in this example)

I don't know how FileInfo works with ICO files, but ImageMagick is probably safer as it really has to decode a significant part of the file.

As ImageMagick supports a lot of formats, it's important to check its output and not simply its return code (it also succeeds with JPG, SVG, etc).

**IcoUtils**

As a lightweight alternative to ImageMagick, IcoUtils can do the trick:

```
$ icotool -l favicon.ico
--icon --index=1 --width=16 --height=16 --bit-depth=32 --palette-size=0
--icon --index=2 --width=32 --height=32 --bit-depth=32 --palette-size=0
--icon --index=3 --width=48 --height=48 --bit-depth=32 --palette-size=0

$ icotool -l not_a_favicon.svg
favicon.svg: not an icon or cursor file (reserved non-zero)
```

Unfortunately its return code is always 0, forcing you to actually check its output.

It can be installed on Ubuntu with:

```
sudo apt-get install icoutils
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Use a tool to convert your png to a ico file. You can search "favicon generator" and you can find many online tools.
2. Place the ico address in the `head` with a `link`-tag:

   ```
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">
   ```

Comment: This is not an answer to OP's question and doesn't even attempt to answer it.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not asking that. I am asking how to detect through a form if a file is favicon or not in a secure way